# Add all DLLs to GAC?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, gac, safe-controls, 2010

My SharePoint 2010 solution has two projects, one responsible for the back end (WCF web service) and one for the front end (webparts). I added the DLL from the back end to GAC via Visual Studio Command Prompt, should I do the same for the front end DLL?

It is in the .wsp solution file, but when I deploy and attempt to add a web part, it gives me an error:

> A web part or web form control on this page cannot be displayed or imported. the type could not be found or a web part is not registered as safe.

While I am investigating the latter, I think the former is the actual problem.

Comment: did you deploy the solution via Visual Studio or Powershell? it should be IN GAC on All server in order to work properly.

Comment: I used command prompt to run a .cmd that calls on a Powershell script. So, Powershell in an indirect way.

Comment: did you add -GACDeployment in your script?

Comment: But only the back end DLL is in GAC. Should I add the front end one via VS command prompt?

Comment: Yes, I added the -GACDeployment parameter to the InstallSolution cmdlet

Comment: So this dll is not on any wfe after this? What is status of solution...check from central...manage farm solution...make sure admin service n timer service running on all servers.

Comment: What is wfe? Currently I retracted and removed the solution. What are the admin and timer services specifically called, and what servers do they need to run on (I assumed just the SharePoint one)?